# Date jumps to year 2285 in Vagrant

Tags: linux, vagrant

It happened yesterday, and today again.

The vagrant box on my machine jumped to the year 2285

```
(venv3.9.0) root@v-yf:/var/log# timedatectl 
                      Local time: Mon 2285-09-21 06:15:40 CET
                  Universal time: Mon 2285-09-21 05:15:40 UTC
                        RTC time: Thu 2021-01-07 14:25:15
                       Time zone: Europe/Berlin (CET, +0100)
       System clock synchronized: no
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

From /var/log/syslog

```
Jan  7 14:35:01 v-yf CRON[5823]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Sep 21 05:32:03 v-yf kernel: [8318599810.152743] hrtimer: interrupt took 80102242147 ns
Sep 21 05:32:03 v-yf kernel: [8318599810.152814] clocksource: timekeeping watchdog on CPU0: Marking clocksource 'tsc' as unstable because the skew is too large:
Sep 21 05:32:03 v-yf kernel: [8318599810.152825] clocksource:                       'kvm-clock' wd_now: 73719a74f60024e0 wd_last: 11027f6d11a9 mask: ffffffffffffffff
Sep 21 05:32:03 v-yf kernel: [8318599810.152834] clocksource:                       'tsc' cs_now: fffff7900a43c874 cs_last: 25b8395a9da9 mask: ffffffffffffffff
Sep 21 05:32:03 v-yf kernel: [8318599810.152843] tsc: Marking TSC unstable due to clocksource watchdog
```

My laptop runs Ubuntu 20.04, Vagrant Ubuntu 18.04

It already happened three times.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Either you went to the futur or there is a bug `80102242147 ns` is about 80s ( 1s = 1 000 000 000 ns)